# Is there a neat way to perform XOR operation on two conditions in IF statement?

Tags: python, binary, logical-operators, xor

I am currently creating a binary calculator which allows for both positive and negative binary inputs. I have the following code regarding my question:

```
if (firstvalue[0] == "-" and not secondvalue[0] == "-") or (secondvalue[0] == "-" and not firstvalue[0] == "-"): 
    invertedbinary.append("-")
```

So obviously, if either number is negative but not both then the final string will have a negative sign. Otherwise, both will be positive and there will be no negative sign on the string.

I'm just wondering if there is a neater way to do this? I tried using `^` but I guess its only a bitwise operator.

`if firstvalue[0] == "-" ^ secondvalue[0] == "-":`

I also tried `xor` incase of the off chance but obviously no luck. Any suggestions on a a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` will work just fine if you use parentheses:

```
if (firstvalue[0] == "-") ^ (secondvalue[0] == "-"):
```

You can also use `!=` in the place of `^`. It works the exact same way here, but may be a little more clear.

Comment: oh man, can't believe I missed something so obvious. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

One thing to remember with `^` is that it will behave unexpectedly if any of the expressions is a non-bool: `a ^ b` does not equal `(a and not b) or (b and not a)` if, say `a = 5` and `b = 2`!

---

Since `xor` can't short-circuit, you can as well use a function.

```
from operator import xor as xor_
from functools import reduce

def xor(*args):
    return reduce(xor_, map(bool, args))

if xor(firstvalue[0] == '-', secondvalue[0] == '-'):
    ...
```

This works for any number of values, and non-boolean values too, so you can do `xor(1, 1, 1, 1) = 0` and `xor(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) = 1`